# Java output as variables within same shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm running JAVA code inside shell script

```
java -cp ojdbc6.jar:. javaClassName args
```

Is it possible to do command substitution for java output inside shell

Output of java code is an array:

```
[{ID:143},{Name:John},{Age:32},{Designation:Enginner},{City:Delhi},{Phone:+123 456 789},{Email:abc@gmai.com}]
```

I want to declare above array as variables inside the same shell-script where java code runs

```
ID=${ID}
Name=${Name}
```

Comment: So: 1.1. Separate input by the comma 2. Extract the relevant strings 3. Parse the text to create a string or strings `ID=143` `Name=John` `Age=32` etc. 4. Then re-evaulate the strings or best use `declare` or use `read` to read the values into current shell. Utilities like `tr` `sed` `awk` will be helpful. What have you tried? Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
grep -oE '(:[^}]+)' |  head -2  | tr -d ':'
```

Demo :

```
$read -r Id Name <<<$(echo '[{ID:143},{Name:John},{Age:32},{Designation:Enginner},{City:Delhi},{Phone:+123 456 789},{Email:abc@gmai.com}]' | grep -oE '(:[^}]+)' |  head -2  | tr -d ':' )
$echo $Id
143
$echo $Name
John
$
```